# How to make a mute/unmute command in discord.py

Tags: discord, discord.py, mute

I was making a mute/unmute command for my bot, but every time I type it out, it won't work. Please help me.

Comment: Hey, you should give details about your error. We can't help you like that

Comment: Its not really a error but when I use the command It just replies to me in visual and says that mute is not a command

Comment: Welcome to Stack Sid_Fieser! When writing a question, please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of the code that you have tried, or the code that you think is problematic. Stackoverflow **is not** a code writing service, but rather a service that will help you improve on what you already have. Do also visit [How to ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for further details. Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a forked version of discord.py, You can use the timeout function on the member object (new feature and is not supported by discord.py as it was discontinued)
However, if you are on discord.py, you can assign and un-assign mute roles after grabbing the member object.